# User defined type not defined error in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I am getting error message in ms access 2003. In access the 2 dll references are already added.

1. GeneralLink
2. CommonLink

I have to remove "CommonLink" reference from access project. I created one project "MyCommonLink" which is same as "CommonLink". When I remove "CommonLink" reference & adding new "MyCommonLink" reference while compiling it gives me "User - defined type not defined" error. Without any line of code highlighting.

Also I was checked that both project's code are same & dll files are registered. 
Can anybody help me for how do I find for which object I am getting this error or which object was remain unreferenced?

could someone help me please? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search in the code pages for "GeneralLink". There must be an object being declared somewhere that is fully qualified starting with GeneralLink (e.g. `Dim x As GeneralLink.SomeObject`). Or maybe there is a Public Enum in GeneralLink that is fully qualified somewhere (e.g. `If x = GeneralLink.MyEnum.Item1 Then`)

Comment: I convert the GeneralLink VB6 referenced object to vb.net referenced object also the Public Enum in GeneralLink referenced to vb.net object. Still getting the same error.